# What is a contemporary version of AC Grayling's Philosophy 1? (a logically rigorous intro one-branch-a-chapter)

Tags: reference-request

I am a math/logic student who has taken your standard basic intro to philosophy course.

I skimmed AC Grayling's Philosophy 1 and 2 books and they are logically rigorous and concise overviews of an entire branch of philosophy per chapter.

But they are from 1995 and 1998, so I am looking for a contemporary version.

Comment: Philosophy does not move at lightning speed, Grayling's book is still pretty contemporary. And elementary texts of this sort would not go into recent developments anyway. But "logically rigorous and concise" is not necessarily a virtue in philosophy.

Comment: "But "logically rigorous and concise" is not necessarily a virtue in philosophy" I'm struggling to think of an example when it wouldn't be?

Comment: @DanielPrendergast Logical rigor is not very useful in ethics or aesthetics (or even speculative metaphysics), and philosophical depth and fruitfulness do not go well with brevity, think of Kant or Hegel.

Comment: @Conifold Commit them then to the flames.

Comment: @Conifold Logical rigour is highly useful in Ethics. Just because it's ethics doesn't mean you just abandon logical arguments and the notion of validity etc and just try to feel your way to the truth.

Comment: @DanielPrendergast Logic, yes, occasionally, rigor, no. In mathematics, you have depth over width, small number of axioms and long inference chains that need rigor control for errors. In ethics it is the opposite, width over depth. Large number of irreducible moral judgments, logical chains, when they are needed, are mostly short and trivial. It is the judgments themselves that are the heart of the subject, they are argued over the most, and logic is of little help there.

Comment: @Conifold but you literally can't argue without logic, otherwise someone makes a  bad argument, and you've got no way of saying that it's bad. I'm only undergraduate level to be fair, but when i've done modules in ethics I've never had the impression that an argument which would be good enough ethics but not for, say, epistemology, just in virtue of its form. The style of reasoning i use for one or the other is identical. The difference lies in the units of data we're arguing with. And stuff like utilitarianism gets pretty mathematical anyway

Comment: @DanielPrendergast Substantive arguments in ethics take general claims, and test them by judging their consequences against moral intuitions in some tricky examples. Then argue that they clash or misfire, and should be qualified so and so. Neither moral intuitions, nor even what would happen in specific cases is determined by logical form, it relies on value and plausibility judgments. Except with novices, moral mistakes and controversies do not come from people affirming consequents or messing up inductions. Look at the reasoning around the trolley problem and double effect, for example.

Comment: @Conifold But the trolly problem is largely about the inconsistency of accepting some instance of the utilitarian answer, but rejecting others. The solution (to that problem within the trolly problem) comes from making subtle distinctions, and showing that those distinctions bettween cases allow the equivalence to come apart. True, you're not like writing down logical symbols or anything, but the reasoning you're doing is still constrained by the logic you, as a philosopher, have picked up. You don't throw out logic, you're just bounded by it, rather than analysing it, and using other skills

Comment: @DanielPrendergast It is more about utilitarian answers clashing with moral intuitions, and most of ethics (deontology, virtue, even consequentialist) is non-utilitarian. I would not object to using "logic" in the colloquial sense, as in heuristic reasoning, but much of that is outside of form and rigor. Recent research also shows that much of "subtle distinctions" in the trolley problem is used to fabricate rationalizations after the fact for emotive judgments, see [Moral Judgment](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260025638_Moral_Judgment).

Comment: @Conifold I still think that if someone in ethics makes an invalid argument, it's legitimate to point that out. And that's all I need for my case to be honest. "form" just means, if someone makes a bad argument in virtue of something other than false premises, you can point it out. "Rigour" is just a throw away term meaning "we're methodologically careful in these parts". And i find the kind of xphilosophy stuff very uninteresting. of course we make emotional moral judgements and rationalise afterwards. That's a cause of why we'd make an argument, not a refutation of the argument itself

Comment: I agree in a vague sense. But to me rigor (as in math and more formal parts of philosophy) means a comprehensive approach to structuring reasoning that would be largely counterproductive in ethics. Moral reasoning is more about balancing clashing values and evoking judgments than about arguing from accepted premises in elaborate ways. And the problem with rationalization is that it passes emotional responses for conclusions of non-existent reasoning. If the argument is supposed to be a reconstruction of such reasoning it need not be refuted, there is nothing to refute.

Answer (score 1):

The "[very short introductions](https://global.oup.com/academic/content/series/v/very-short-introductions-vsi/?cc=us&lang=en&)" may be what you are looking for. They cover topics in philosophy. Here is Wikipedia's description:

> Very Short Introductions (VSI) are a book series published by the Oxford University Press (OUP). The books are concise introductions to particular subjects, intended for a general audience but written by experts. Most are under 200 pages long. While authors may present personal viewpoints, the books are meant to be "balanced and complete" as well as thought provoking.

Two other sources to keep in mind are the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/) and the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://www.iep.utm.edu/).

Although these are not all in one book, they are short and give you exposure to more than one author.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, August 22). Very Short Introductions. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 14:48, September 10, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Very_Short_Introductions&oldid=912030519

Answer (score 0):

Conifold is so right. Philosophy doesn't date so quickly as works in most other subjects.

So Grayling 1 is ok though the quality does swing a bit from chapter to chapter. You might also want to consider :

The Blackwell Companion to Philosophy (Blackwell Companions to Philosophy)
by Nicholas Bunnin and Eric Tsui–James. 2nd ed., 2002. You can look inside on Amazon under:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=ISBN+10%3A+0631219072+%2F+ISBN+13%3A+9780631219071&ref=nb_sb_noss